# Testing unprocessable_entity in standard rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

With the goal of getting coverage for a line that,
if the object cannot be saved
`render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity`
writing a test, for a class where `Post belongs_to :user`, such as

```
    assert_no_difference "Post.count" do
      post posts_path,  params: { post: { user_id: nil }  }
    end
    assert_response :unprocessable_entity
```

will in practice never reach the response stage as `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:` will be invoked beforehand.

A block test `assert_response :unprocessable_entity do` generates
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'response_code' for nil:NilClass`

This test appears somewhat moot because it would be covered upstream by a validity test.  Still, the curiosity of possibly bypassing the validation test interrupt is strong...

Can unprocessable_entity be tested under standard rails framework?

Comment: This just sounds like the code under test is flawed. The only reason `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` would be raised if is you're using the bang methods like `save!` or `create!`. They should not be used for normal flow in a controller as invalid input is not an exceptional event. Instead use the normal methods and check the return value.

Comment: Also you should really write this test properly with one assertation per test. Your second assertation relies on `assert_no_difference` to setup the test for it which is quite smelly.

Comment: the bang method had been put in to extract validation errors, then fogotten... and remained unseen (it hides well).  The thought never arose; good to be bitten an learn.

Comment: Yeah, "Just use create!" is some awful advice that keeps getting parroted on SO by juniors. If you want to do quick debugging use a debugger like byebug or pry instead so that you don't have to change the implementation of the method.